# Edit Field Name In Attribute Table (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, editing, fields-attributes, string

This seems like such a simple task, yet after researching how to execute it in QGIS I've been unsuccessful.  I'm merely trying to rename columns in my attribute table.  My existing field is currently named "employment", and I would like to rename it "BG_Desc".

I've read the "table manager" plug-in will do this, but it appear the plug-in is no longer available for version 3.0.

I've used the "replace" tool under "String" in the field calculator, but it does not work when I enter the following:

```
replac("employment",employment","BG_Desc")
```

Suggesstions?